# Using Github Gallery, unable to confine it to container div

Tags: javascript, css, gallery

I found a gallery on Github and downloaded it to try on a test site. It is Javascript and CSS; no flash. This is my site's main page.  I made it a while back to test for responsiveness, as far as the footer is concerned:
[Main Page](http://yipcabbage.com/2ColTemplate/)

This page is the Github gallery, simply uploaded to my test site with no changes.  (I left the Github fork banner, which takes you directly to the project page.)

[Polaroids](http://yipcabbage.com/2ColTemplate/polaroids.html)

I have been trying to incorporate the gallery into an existing webpage, but it breaks any and all pages that I've tried it on.  No div will contain it and no footer will stay.  (I've tried this with and without the gallery's navbar, which is fixed and has a 0 bottom margin but removing it makes no difference.)  This is what a page looks like when the gallery is added:

[Test Gallery](http://yipcabbage.com/2ColTemplate/gallery.html)

Can anyone determine if this gallery can actually be edited to fit within a site design's confines, or if it is fullscreen only?  I've been unsuccessful contacting the author.

EDIT TO ADD:  It looks like my footer DID stay (so yay for that) but the issue of breaking confines is still there.

Comment: The library is clearly not meant to be confined in a div (it uses `window`'s dimensions to scatter the images. Adding a target option to it is not really a challenge, but since you haven't put any coding effort... why would anyone else? Besides, you always have the `<iframe>` workaround.

Comment: Alright, Andrei; that'll just be the answer, then.  It's not meant to.  You've answered the question and I wouldn't dream of asking for further help.  Not at this site.  I remember now why I stopped coming.  *sigh*  Thanks for explaining.  I'll move on (literally).

Comment: [<iframe>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe) is a perfectly valid solution for your case. Please read [ask]. Nobody asked you to move on. I stated the obvious: your question doesn't show research or coding effort, which is likely to stop others from helping out.